# Returning parameter instead of passing it by Ref

Tags: c#

I see sometimes method that has a parameter, modifies it and returns it. 
Is there any advantage of that, why no simply pass the parameter by ref and keep the method by `ref`?

Here is what I see:

```
public MyClass DoSomething(MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Amount = 500;
    return myClass;
}
```

Why not keep it simple like this:

```
public void DoSomething(ref MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Amount = 500;
}
```

Comment: ref MyClass myClass has no much sense if myClass is a class, that has sense if myClass is a struct.

Comment: You don't need to add ref in second method.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti Actually `ref` makes sense if you want to overwrite the instance.

Comment: "I see sometimes method that has a parameter, modifies it and returns it" such a construct actually makes it quite obvious that a change to the object was made when you read the code. you don't need to dive into the method to see what it does if you see a line like `x = DoSomething(x)`

Comment: Here's a good blog by Jon Skeet that covers reference types and how that's different from passing by reference https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Yes, that way you can chain them up: `MyClass x = myClass.DoSomethingA ().DoSomethingB ().DoSomethingC ()` - Note however, there is no reason to provide the instance as parameter if the method is within the class... unless it's a static extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `ref` keyword only makes sense if you intend to change the reference of your parameter. In general, you want to avoid this, but if you feel like you must:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say the myClass parameter has `Id = 1`, `Amount = 300`.

This works:

```cs
public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass) 
{
    myClass.Amount = 500;
}
```

`myClass.Amount` has become `500`.

This does NOT work:

```cs
public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass) 
{
    myClass = new MyClass()
    {
         Id = 5,
         Amount = 500
    }
}
```

`myClass.Amount` is still `300` and `myClass.Id` is `1`.

But, this DOES work:

```cs
public void DoSomething(ref MyClass myClass) 
{
    myClass = new MyClass()
    {
         Id = 5,
         Amount = 500
    }
}
```

`myClass.Amount` is `500` and `myClass.Id` is `5`.

Answer (score 2):

If `MyClass` is reference type in sample below

```cs
public MyClass DoSomething(MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Amount = 500;
    return myClass;
}
```

it doesn't make sense to return it, because all reference types are passed by reference and you can do something like that

```
public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Amount = 500;
}
```

It makes sense only when `MyClass` is value type (inherits `struct`).

However, there is new type `ref structs` introduced in .NET Core, which is used to allocate a `struct` type in a stack and pass them by reference, not by value (without copying). You can read at [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref?view=netcore-3.0#ref-struct-types)

Comment: Actually returning the object like this is useful for chaining calls together,

Comment: Yes, some kind of fluent API, but OP doesn't mention about this point

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, if `MyClass` is reference type, `ref` doesn't make much sense.

But returning passed argument makes sense, because it returns explicitly modified parameter, so it works for structs and classes. And is more readable, which is very good thing.

Also, if we're talking about reference types, `ref` is unnecessary and code without it is cleaner.

Comment: Actually, it can make sense if you want to allow the method to overwrite the entire object with a new one.